# How to open the phpfox main menu link in seperate tab

Tags: php

i am using phpfox free s/w, i like to do some changes in the phpfox main page menu., I add new menu through the admin cpanel-> CMS -> menus -> Add menus. There i can specify the menu name and it corresponding href link. my issue is if i click the menu it open the page in same tab, but i want to open particular menu link in separate tab.  How it possible plz guide me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Click on something and it will open a new tab.

```
<a href="somewhere" target="_blank">something</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to do. follow this 
on the language pack where you would put the name of the tab ad this into the name area.

```
<a href="http://yoursite/" target="_blank">yoursite name as this is
 the title users will see</a>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

the admin cpanel-> CMS -> menus -> Add menus/edit menus.....Language Package Details ..just add the following code...

{`a href="http://mysite.com/index.php?do=/module_name/controller" target="_blank">Your_menu_name</a>`}
Thanks